# How does signal to noise ratio work in the OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I wonder how I can implement surrounding noise signals in OMNeT++.
As far as I know, there is an SNR box that I can input the number as a percentage, but I don't see it in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the wrong place. OMNeT++ does not implement anything regarding SNR, because it is a generic discrete event simulator that does not know anything about domain models.

What you are speaking is INET framework, which is a network simulation model (written for OMNeT++). So, you have to look for documentation on the model's website, not in the generic omnet manual. There is detailed documentation about the transmission modeling and noise models, for example here: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-transmission-medium.html#background-noise-models